# File contents filtering

Tags: c#, csv, file-io

I'm trying to develop an application which will take the data from a datagrid and based on a drop down menu choice return a csv file with only the selected client . My code is shown below , This links to a previous question I posted howeever I am still getting no values back and I really need to sort this out so I'm wondering if anyone can either see were i'm going wrong or else provide alternatives

```
    //Master inventory export 
    private void ExportClass_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
        objSqlCommands2 = new SqlCommands("MasterInventory", "ClientName");
        string strString = str.ToString();
        string Filepath = txtSaveShareClass.Text.ToString();
        str.Append("ISIN ,FundName,Status,Share CCY,Benchmark,NAV  Freq,CLASSCODE,SIMULATION,HEDGED,FUNDCCY");

        StringManipulation sm = new StringManipulation();

        foreach (DataRow dr in this.CalcDataSet.MasterInventory)
        {
            foreach (object field in dr.ItemArray)
            {
                str.Append(field.ToString() + ",");
             }

            str.Replace(",", "\n", str.Length - 1, 1);
        }

        try
        {
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(Filepath, str.ToString());

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Write Error :" + ex.Message);
        }

        List<string[]> lsClientList =  objStringManipulation.parseCSV(Filepath,cmbClientList .Text.ToCharArray());


        foreach (string[] laClient in lsClientList)
        {
            sm.parseCSV2(Filepath, cmbClientList.Text.ToCharArray());
            List<string[]> newFoo = lsClientList.Where(x =>  x.Contains(cmbClientList.Text)).ToList();
            List<string[]> Results = sm.parseCSV2(Filepath,    cmbClientList.Text.ToCharArray()).Where(x => x.Contains(cmbClientList.Text)).ToList();

            //Refreshs the Client table on display from the 
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(Filepath, Results.ToString());             
        }

        this.TableAdapter.Fill(this.CalcDataSet.MasterInventory);

        dataGridView2.Update();

    }
```

Comment: So where is the problem? Is the CSV file written correctly? Is it read back correctly? Does `newFoo` get the results you expect? Does `Results` get the results you expect? Calling `ToString()` on the `Results` isn't going to give you anything useful. You have to enumerate it to get the strings. You need to give us some idea of where your problem lies, otherwise we have nowhere to start giving you help.

Comment: I dont know where the problem is from what i can see and others i've shown it should work , yes csv is correct , no it gets 0 results....ok sorry , I thought the question had shown were the problem was it said i neeed to get the proper results as spoken about it the question

Comment: Are you running this in the debugger, single-stepping and examining the results of each operation? That's the only way you're going to figure out where the problem is.

Comment: yeah went through and same again i cant see a problem , the variables are filling correctly

Answer (score 1):

If all of your variables are filling properly and your `Results` list contains the data that you expect, then the problem is with your `WriteAllText` call. You have:

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(Filepath, Results.ToString());
```

That is not going to produce the output that you seem to expect. It will likely just give you the class name.

`Results` is a `List<string[]>`. If you want to output that as a CSV, then you have to enumerate it:

```
using (var outfile = new StreamWriter(Filepath))
{
    foreach (var line in Results)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var field in line)
        {
            sb.Append(field + ",");
        }
        sb.Length = sb.Length -1;
        outfile.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
    }
}
```